# $x^{n}$ such that n is positive and odd, the range is all real numbers. Prove it.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

What I think the answer is : The range is the set of all real numbers because we can have a number $x^1$ that is equal to $x^2$

Specifically, to access even powers of n, all we need do is scale up x of the odd powers.

And since the function is not a quotient or a square root, there are no constraints of the functions domain. Therefore, since the domain is the set of all real numbers, the range is the set of all real numbers as well.

Comment: *Why* is $x^1$ equal to $x^2$?

Comment: Well, x being the independent variable can be 1. $1^1$ == $1^2$.

Comment: Sure. And it can be $14$. And $14^1\ne14^2$.

Comment: The statement basically wants to say that "for every real number $a$, there exists a number $x$ belonging to set of real numbers, such that $a^{\frac{1}{2k+1}}=x$

Comment: Use the fact that $x^n$ is unbounded in both directions - which can be proved by working with integers alone: given $r\in R$ there is a positive integer $m$ with $(-m)^n\lt r \lt m^n$ and then use the fact that $x^n$ is continuous and therefore has the intermediate value property (which belongs to the real numbers).

Comment: You posed the problem very tersely in the title, and omitted a careful statement of the problem (its setup and goal) from the body of your Question.  Although you have an understanding of the problem, Readers will often be unable to infer what help you want.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the range of all functions of the type $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$ $f(x) = x^n,$ where $n \in 2 \mathbb{N} + 1$ is the entire $\mathbb{R}$ is that obviously all of these mappings are continuous, which can be readily verified and also $\lim_{x \to -\infty} x^n = -\infty,$ $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^n = \infty$ and a simple application of Darboux's property helps you get your conclusion.

Comment: I'm on section 1.1 in my calculus book, I don't have access to those tools yet so I'm not going to accept this answer for now. But I will say that it is correct.

Comment: Oh, okay then, I see. Then do you know that $x \mapsto x^n$ is bijective when $n \in 2 \mathbb{N} + 1?$ Because this is in fact all you need to deduce your desired conclusion. Actually you are only interested in the surjectivity part, for which it is easy to see that $(x^\frac{1}{n})^n = x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and since $n$ is odd, the root is well defined.

Comment: I'm familiar, yes and thank you.

Comment: You're most welcome. :)